# AP aggregation using WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, tyk

I have a requirement of aggregating multiple APIs i.e. combining responses of two or more APIs. I was wondering if that can be achieved through WSO2 API Manager. TYK supports it in the form of 'virtual Endpoints'. How about WSO2 API Manager ? Any help appreciated.

Comment: I am actually looking for a way to do this too. Came across this. May not be exactly what you are looking at but can give you some idea. https://docs.wso2.com/display/IntegrationPatterns/Aggregator

Answer (score 3):

Technically, this can be made byt the API Manager Gateway, since the gateway is an embedded version of the ESB gateway, so you can mediate all calls. See  [WSO2 EI documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI630/Exposing+Several+Services+as+a+Single+Service) Be aware that in the API gateway there are some restriction, you have to use blocking calls .

However, the API Gateway should not be used to do "integration" of services if you want it to be highly scalable.

Could you elaborate on your specific needs ?

call API A then call API B with some A info and then produce a result ?
Or more slogic like if API A yelds value X then call B else call C ?

If your need is API composition (multiple calls) you should use an integraiton layer. Either using code framework, like springBoot/Cloud or GraphQL server (superb tool to invoque multiple APIs) or WSO2 Integration solutions like Ballerina (micro compositions) or the WSO2 ESB (but it is from the monolithic world).

I hope it helps
Cyril